# Update field in MS-Access based on conditions

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have written this query to update a field of a table.

```
Update Application as A, Details as D set A.[Group] = D.[Group]
where D.Code = A.Code
```

The group field in Details table values are from SQL and if the values are like `''` (means blank cell) and `NULL`, then I need to update the Application Group field as `N/A`.

Can anyone suggest me to sort this out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following SQL

```
UPDATE Details INNER JOIN Application ON Details.Group = Application.Group SET Application.[Group] = 'N/A'
WHERE (((Application.Group)=''));
```